Morphisms as Homomorphisms
It is usually said that when we consider the category of groups, the morphisms are homomorphisms. The category of groups can also be considered as a category of sets and morphisms as usual functions, right? I agree that such "stripping" of group status may not lead to anything worthwhile especially if we want to study groups.
Am I missing anything here in the sense that the composition/identity/associativity somehow
makes a morphism on the category Group an actual homomorphism? Sorry, I am self-learning Category theory. 

No, the category of groups is not just the category of sets with morphisms.  A group is not just a set, but has more data than that:  namely, the binary operation.  To strip this is to remove all of the essence of the group.

This is an example of a "forgetful functor." Oddly, there is no definition for the term, but it essentially means send objects to an object of strictly less structure. So, for example, treating rings as additive abelian groups.

Given the category of all groups $\mathbf{Grp}$ and the category of all sets $\mathbf{Set}$ we do have the forgetful functor $F:\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Set}$ which maps each group to its underlying set, and each homomorphism to itself (since it already is a function between sets). Forgetful functors are of interest, yes.
But you ask about category, not functor. So the way I see it, you ask whether the image of the forgetful functor $F$ is actually a category. Note that this is a valid question, since it is not necessarily true that an image of a functor is a category. The reason for this is that it may happen that we have a morphism $\alpha:A\to B$ and $\beta:C\to D$, where $B\neq C$ so these are not composable. But our functor maps $F(B)=F(C)$ and so after applying the functor they are composable. Then the question arises: does $F(\beta)\circ F(\alpha)$ belong to the image? Or in other words is $F(\beta)\circ F(\alpha)=F(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma$? This is necessary for the image to be a category.
And in fact, the forgetful functor $F:\mathbf{Grp}\to\mathbf{Set}$ is an example of a functor such that the image is not a category. Indeed, consider the embedding $f:\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_6$ and the quotient map $g:\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_3$. Say $g(0)=0$ and $g(2)=1$. Now, I can rearrange group operation on $\mathbb{Z}_6$ so that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=2$ is the embedding. Note that I've just created a new group, but the underlying set is the same. So even though I am not allowed to compose those functions as homomorphisms, I can compose them as functions. In such situation the composition $g\circ f$ maps $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$. Such function cannot arise as a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}_3$, regardless of how we choose group structures on them (all such homomorphisms are necessarily constant).
In other words: the forgetful functor is not the same thing as treating groups just as sets, and homomorphisms just as functions. There's a locality involved, the functor won't allow arbitrary morphism composition.
But the good news is that if $F(\beta)\circ F(\alpha)$ actually does arise as $F(\gamma)$ for all morphisms $\beta,\alpha$ (in particular when $F$ is full), then indeed the image is a category. You don't have to worry about composition, identity and associativity. Functoriality guarantees that. Well, you do have to prove that $F$ is a functor though.
Another situation when the image is a category is when the functor is injective, i.e. when $F(A)=F(B)$ implies $A=B$. So for example the forgetful functor may still work, if we consider some subcategory of $\mathbf{Grp}$, more precisely a subcategory where no two distinct groups have the same underlying set. This situation implies the previous one because $F(\beta)\circ F(\alpha)$ is allowed only when $\beta\circ\alpha$ is, and then by functoriality $F(\beta)\circ F(\alpha)=F(\beta\circ\alpha)$.

Although I don't think that's what the OP meant, this is a nice and interesting interpretation of that question, (+1).

Terrific, thank you. Like @Trebor says, I didn't think of this as deep as you answered, but glad to know about forgetful functors and why an image of a functor need not be a category.

The interpretation I read from your question, which is a bit different from those mentioned so far, is: is there a category whose objects are groups and such that the morphisms $f:G\to H$ between any two groups are simply arbitrary functions between the underlying sets of $G$ and $H$? There certainly is such a category. One general construction is, given any functor $F:C\to D,$ to factor $F$ as a functor that's the identity on objects followed by one that's fully faithful--essentially, we can always "apply $F$ on morphisms" and then separately "apply $F$ on objects." This produces an intermediate category $E$ whose objects are those of $C$ and whose morphisms between two objects of $C$ are the morphisms between their images in $D.$ Above we applied this construction to the special case of the forgetful functor out of groups.
Note this doesn't contradict the issue about the image of a functor not always being a category, because we're allowing all functions between the underlying sets of two groups, not just those coming from homomorphisms. Note also that this category is pretty boring, insofar as it's very nearly equivalent to sets: by definition it comes with a fully faithful functor into sets, which would be an equivalence if it were essentially surjective. Every nonempty set admits some group structure, so this category is equivalent to the category of nonempty sets and arbitrary functions.

The category of groups is defined as the category whose objects are groups (that is, sets equipped with the structure of a group) and whose morphisms $G \to H$ are group homomorphisms (that is, functions between the underlying sets of $G$ and $H$ equipped with the property of preserving the group structures).
There is a (faithful) forgetful functor $\mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ which sends a group to its underlying set and a group homomorphism to its underlying function, making $\mathbf{Grp}$ a concrete category.
